# Defining string packs with different content but same structure in android resources

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, android-resources

I have a game where I have a hierarchy where a season has multiple levels and a level has multiple tasks.

Now, I have an Activity that shows a congratulatory message for each of these parts of the hierarchy which are divided in different strings. Each of them have:

- Exclamation
- Header
- Description
- Continue Message

For example season:

- "HURRAY!"
- "Season Finished"
- "You have successfully finished season X"
- "Continue to season X+1"

My first idea was to create an enum that holds the appropriate values. Like this:

```
enum class CongratulationsType(val exclamation: String, val header: String) {
    SEASON("HURRAY!", "You finished season %d!!"),
    LEVEL("YAY!", "Well done! Level over!"),
    TASK("NICE!", "This looked too easy")
}
...
val headerString = CongratulationsType.SEASON.header
```

But strings should be saved in resources. So I would have to put the strings into the resources and correctly link the resources to the enum values.

This would mean that I kinda do the work twice. I would define the strings in the resource file without a "binding structure", just to then put them into the enum to have a "binding structure". By "binding structure" I mean the structure described above where it's mandatory for the specific fields to exist and where I would be able to call something like `CongratulationsType.SEASON.header`.

My question is: Is it possible to "pack" strings in some defined structure and have that structure be something like an enum or a hashmap? Something like:

**Pack definition**

```
<resources>
   <pack_def name="congrats">
      <string name="exclamation"/>
      <string name="header"/>
      ...
   </pack_def>
<resources>
```

**Pack implementation**

```
<resources>
   <pack name="season" type="congrats">
      <string name="exclamation">HURRAY!</string>
      <string name="header">Season Finished</string>
      ...
   </pack>
<resources>
```

**Usage**

```
// In code
//// function definition
fun setMessage(congrats: Congrats) {
    exclamationTextView.text = congratsType.exclamation
    headerTextView.text = congratsType.header
    ...
}
    
//// function use
setMessage(Congrats.Season)

// In Resources
<TextView
    android:text="@packs/congrats/season/exclamation"
/>
```

I know that I could use string array resources but they seem a little bit "unclean" because, as I said, I want the structure to be "binding" and called like enums. I'm specifically asking for a way to do it as close to enums as possible without having to assign a resource to each field for each enum value.

Comment: This might help? 
https://github.com/WhatsApp/StringPacks

Comment: Sadly not really what I am looking for. The link you provided describes a way to be more for storing different languages more efficiently, rather than creating a new structure and comes with more overhead than the direct enum-option described in my question

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: Is it possible to "pack" strings in some defined structure and have that structure be something like an enum or a hashmap? Something like:
>
> `android:text="@packs/congrats/season/exclamation"`

Short answer - no. Android will not know how to parse and extract values from these new structures.

What you can do:

1. Create 4 string resource arrays: Exclamations, Headers, Descriptions, Continue Messages;
2. Create kotlin data class with 4 string variables. Let's call it `Congratulation`;
3. Map resources to an array with of `Congratulation`s.

Example:

In strings.xml file you declare next arrays:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="exclamations">
        <item>Exclamation 1!!!</item>
        <item>Exclamation 2!!!</item>
        ...
        <item>Exclamation N!!!</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="headers">
        <item>Header 1</item>
        <item>Header 2</item>
        ...
        <item>Header N</item>
    </string-array>
    
    <!-- etc. -->
</resources>
```

Or you can use already defined resources in these arrays just to order them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="exclamations">
        <item>@string/exclamation_1</item>
        <item>@string/exclamation_2</item>
        ...
        <item>@string/exclamation_n</item>
    </string-array>

    <!-- etc. -->
</resources>
```

Define data class:

```
data class Congratulation(val exclamation: String, val header: String, 
                          val description: String, val continueMessage: String)
```

Map resources:

```
val exclamations = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.exclamations)
val headers = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.headers)
val descriptions = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions)
val continueMessages = context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.continue_messages)

val congratulations = exclamations.mapIndexed { i, exclamation ->
    Congratulation(exclamation, headers[i], descriptions[i], continueMessages[i])
}
```

**Pros**

- No need to mention each string resource in code, only 4 array resources;
- Following the first point, each time you add new value you don't need to modify your code. You can initialize this array at the moment of application launch once and use later.

**Cons**

- Order of translations must be precise! If you accidentally change order within `<string-array>` - no warning will appear. You will have to check the order manually or create specific tests;
- If accidentally you add fewer entries to any of the `headers`, `descriptions` or `continueMessages` array - the app will crash with `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Although, it will crash as soon as you try to map values and it is easy to debug.
- Using `when` statements becomes impossible.

Comment: That is basically the thing I want a better alternative for. I usually would structure my arrays by type (season, level, task) instead of by field like you did (exclamation, header, etc.). But that is exactly the thing I want a cleaner version of that better incorporates the resources and some form of compile time check.

Comment: If you want compile-time check there will be no other way around it except your solution. Maybe it can be altered, but generally speaking, you will have to do the work "twice" - the exact issue you wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but just in case the only things changing in your messages are the season numbers, you can use [format strings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#formatting-strings) and pass in the appropriate numbers when you display the messages:

```
<string name="continue_message">Continue to season %d</string>

continueTextView.text = getString(R.string.continue_message, season+1)
```

If you do want to be able to set arbitrary strings for each season or whatever, Jenea has it right I think - there's no way to enforce a structure in the strings XML like that (I'm not totally familiar with the XML format in general, you can do some fancy things with it but I think they're limited in what Android will actually interpret and use). You can do runtime validation (maybe only in debug builds, with a *thorough* check across all locales) but you have to design things so you catch any problems that might occur

---

**edit** just to make it clear what I mean about the templates

If you effectively have 4 strings, it's just that you have lots of variations depending on things like season number, level number etc, you might be able to use format strings so you you only *need* exactly 4 in your strings file:

```
<string name="season_exclamation">HURRAY!</string>
<string name="level_exclamation">YAY!</string>
<string name="season_header">You finished season %d!!</string>
<string name="level_header">Well done! Level over!</string>
```

That way you're enforcing a structure, there's no variable length arrays or anything - you have exactly 4 string resources, with 4 specific IDs (and if you end up localising them, it will warn you if you haven't provided them all).

So you can easily make an enum, it's just that your strings are defined in a different place

```
enum class Congratulations(
    @StringRes private val headerResId: Int,
    @StringRes private val exclamationResId: Int
) {
    SEASON(R.string.season_header, R.string.season_exclamation),
    LEVEL(R.string.level_header, R.string.level_exclamation);

    fun getHeader(context: Context) = context.getString(headerResId)
    // etc
}
```

The only tricky thing is you need to pass in that context to pull out the appropriate string resources, instead of just declaring string literals. If you want, you could set a `Context` on the class (early, before you access any strings) and do something like this

```
enum class Congratulations(
    ...
    ...
    companion object {
        lateinit var context: Context
    }

    val header: String get() = context.getString(R.string.header)
    // or, so you only grab the strings once
    val exclamation: String by lazy { context.getString(R.string.exclamation) }
}
```

---

The point about the format strings is that you don't need to create separate string resources for "bla bla season 1" and "bla bla season 2" and constantly add to the `strings` file, if you can use of a template string you could have a function on your enum like `fun getContinueMessage(seasonNumber): String` and then you don't need SEASON1, SEASON2, SEASON3 enums. Although at that point, you're better off using a sealed class since not all your `Congratulation` types will need that, and sealed classes will let you include different objects instead of an enum where everything is the exact same type

Comment: No, as I said. I want it to work like enum. Its not about formating, but about having a enum-like resource structure with multiple strings. Just like the enum I defined in my question.

Comment: I've added a bit about how you'd use them in an enum, the point I was making about format strings is it (might) let you have a fixed number of resources, with specific individual IDs, so that enforces some structure at least - you don't get that with arrays with arbitrary contents

Comment: I've altered the example strings for my enum, which were admittedly misleading. The strings for different headers, exclamations, descriptions and continuationMessages are totally different.

Comment: Yeah, so if you put each of those in the ``strings`` file they'll have their own unique IDs and you just pass those into the enum constructor instead of string literals. The only difference is that you have to ``get`` the string for each ID at some point, like in the examples I gave

Comment: I see what you are getting at. But, as I described in the question, that is exactly the thing I want an alternative to.